# How to multiplay two text_field and display in another text_field without submitting in Rails(using jQuery or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hi I am trying to mulitiplay two text_field(input) value and display it in another text_field(input) in Rails

for example like in jquery we do like this please test it http://jsfiddle.net/qw5xM/

I want this thing in rails how to do that, what i am missing here

my form is bellow

```
    <%= form_for @fills, url: { action: "show"}, method: :get do |f| %>
    //updated code
     <div class="row text-center row-create" style="margin-left: 0%">
        <div class="pull-right col-create" style="margin-right: 0%; border-radius: 50%;">
          <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
            <%= f.button "+" , class: 'btn btn-default bg-red', style: 'border-radius:50%' %>
          </div>
        </div>
// till here                      
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
         <%= f.hidden_field :price, value: @price_log.price   %>
         <%= f.text_field :quantity, value: 1, required: true,  class:'form-control', id: 'quantiy', placeholder: 'Quantity' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <%= f.text_field :amount, value: :total_price ,  class:'form-control', placeholder: 'Amount', id: 'total_price' %>
        </div>
       </div>
     <% end %>
```

and my jquery code is

```
    $('text_field[name="quantity"]').keyup(function() {
     var a = $('hidden_field[name="price"]').val();
     var b = $(this).val();
     $('text_field[name="total_price"]').val(a * b);
    });
```

> **Updated Question**

creating the new fields by clicking plus button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','.col-create',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var cont = $(this).closest('.row-create').clone();
        $(cont).find(".col-create").remove().end().insertAfter($(this).closest('.row-create'));
        e.preventDefault()*;

    });
```

On click plus button it should be create new field same as above and the multiplying script should work separately for each new fields.
I want to create new one and save all new created values also.

But this one saving only first value.

please any help must appriceated

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you still facing this issue, feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you,it will also be beneficial for future stack overflow searcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its always good practice to select an attribute with id or class instead of name attribute, 
provide a id to hidden field price to get its value easily, rest all are good so far and try this: -

```
<%= f.hidden_field :price, value: @price_log.price, id: "price"  %> 



  $('#quantiy').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    $('#total_price').val((price * quantity).toFixed(2));
  });
```

Comment: This is working fine :) I would like to accept this one. but in my code I have one plus button that copy the same code above(two text field for input and one for output) on that case its not working, hope you solve it. Happy to see your answer :)

Comment: any how i will put that too in my code(question) please check it once. and please suggest me to any changes

Comment: @BharatMane So far as i guessed , you want to on click `+` to append new text fields with `quantity,price, and total` . am i right? and you also want to run the same script to calculate total price on keyup . but let me suggest you this will not work reason being: - 1) Even you will able to append those fields, will have same name and at controller you will get `params` with same name and it will always be your last input fields. -2) you will always be some different name to get all fields value at controller....

Comment: @BharatMane In this situation i will suggest you either you should use nested attributes or cocoon gem or you can think it in another way with jquery. or using ajax append another partial in that div with same input fields,hope fully you understand this. well let me know for further guidance. thank you.

Comment: Actually I am trying that, I have a form that calculate above your ans part  and I have one submit button for submitting those values and it should be preserve the all the values on those field.     I have one `+` button for create new row(included all above field empty). and that row should feed the data and preserve 
 data after submit.similarly same continue for `+` button.    can you please help me to get out of this problem. Thanks lot for your valuable answer and suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

you can also write

```
 $('input[name="textbox2"]').keyup(function() {
        var first = $('input[name="textbox1"]').val();
        var second = $(this).val();
        $('input[name="textbox3"]').val(first * second);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` like this:

```
$('.text_field[name="quantity"]').keyup(function() {
     var a = $('hidden_field[name="price"]').val();
     var b = $(this).val();
     $('.text_field[name="total_price"]').val(parseFloat(a) * parseFloat(b));
});
```

Comment: Yaah you might right its gives accurate value but how to make work this function in **Rails** way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `text_field` into `input` because you cannot use [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) with class or id. With [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) you can do with following code.

```js
$('input[name="quantity"]').keyup(function() {
     var a = $('input[name="price"]').val();
     var b = $(this).val();
     $('input[name="total_price"]').val(a * b);
});
```

And with selector you need . for class and # for id. Here is the working code.

```js
$("#quantity").keyup(function() {
  var a = $("#price").val();
  var b = $(this).val();
  $("#total_price").val(a * b);
});
```

Comment: this is wrong, you can not select name attributes with `.` .

Comment: @Gabbar exactly. Thank you for your comment. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Did you see any html attribute with id `price` ? before write this line of code `var a = $("#price").val();` :D lol, please don't copy answer to add in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code

```
$('text_field[name="quantity"]').keyup(function() {
  var a = $('hidden_field[name="price"]').val();
  var b = $(this).val();
  $('text_field[name="total_price"]').val(a * b);
});
```

to

```
$('input[name="quantity"]').keyup(function() {
  var a = $('input[name="price"]').val();
  var b = $('input[name="quantity"]').val();
  $('text_field[name="total_price"]').val(a * b);
});
```

Before writing code, inspect in your browser.

Also, there is something to consider in your logic.

If you enter '3' in first textbox and then enter '4' in second textbox, then the third box will get '12' as value.

But if you again, go to first textbox and change it to '5', it will not print '15'.

So you can change the code as below

```
$('input[name="quantity"]').keyup(function() {
  var a = $('input[name="price"]').val();
  var b = $('input[name="quantity"]').val();
  $('text_field[name="total_price"]').val(a * b);
});

function multiply() {
  var a = $('input[name="price"]').val();
  var b = $(this).val();
  $('text_field[name="total_price"]').val(a * b);
});


$('input[name="quantity"]').keyup(multiply);
$('input[name="price"]').keyup(multiply);
```

Comment: that is fine I want to work it in **Rails** Format. It change after our cursor goes on next text_field.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by **Rails** way. There is no such rails format as you are expecting for javascript. You use the same way in rails too. But before that, you have to include jQuery library. You can do that with `jquery-rails` gem.